# Error installing MikTEX 2.9.6069 under Windows 10

Tags: miktex, installing

When trying to install basic-miktex-2.9.6069-x64 at W10, I get the following error:[image]

Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you.
Víctor

Comment: I don't use MitTeX but it would probably help if you gave a few more details such as what you did to get this error.

Comment: I am sorry about my explanation. Not enough information. Anyway, I have been a couple of days reinstalling the whole W10 since it was making funny things. I think it was a matter of the registry. After that I installed the MikTEX software without problems and I could run LaTeX perfectly. So I am ready to "play" LaTeX again and compose my docs. Thank you so much for your soon answer. Regards.
Víctor

Comment: Can you explain **exactly** how did you solve it?

Comment: I suppose you are the same user of the question, if this is true, please don't sign up every time, only a sign in is necessary.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, I just reinstalled Windows 10 x64 again. It was not a matter of MikTEX but the operating system. On the other hand, I also downloaded all the packages (not the basic installation of MikTEX). Having experienced this full installation, I can say I prefer this way due to the computer does not need to connect and download packages when compiling.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me today. MikTeX update downloade two packages and aborted the package database update, for some problem.

I repeated the update process and learned that both packages were already installed. Therefore I loaded MiKTeX options and manually instructed "Refresh FNDB" and after that, "Update formats".

One week earlier, I have a similar problem with mkfntmap.exe; what I did was 
to open a command window in C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin, and ran "mkfntmap.exe --force" and the program run without problems.

Just as a precaution in both situation I turned off my antivirus program.